# PostgreSQL pg_dumpall Loses Schemas

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I have a postgres database and I'm trying to use pg_dumpall to create the full script to reproduce my database (also using github to keep track of versions of the dump file).

My question is, why does pg_dumpall lose my database schemas? For instance, I have a schema called "go1". My pg_dumpall script should produce a file with "go1.users" for instance for my users table in schema "go1". But the dump file only produces "users". It loses the schema name.

Is there a way for pg_dumpall to preserve the schemas in the dump file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not lose it. View the generated file - you will find `search_path` before creating schema objects, like:

```
...
SET search_path = instruction, pg_catalog;

SET default_tablespace = '';

SET default_with_oids = false;

--
-- Name: file; Type: TABLE; Schema: instruction; Owner: postgres
--

CREATE TABLE file (
    details jsonb,
...
```

would mean it will create **instruction.file** table

Comment: Thanks. Makes sense. So with that path, the query is operating in the context of those schemas. Nice.